# Get pending messages from a Chat

Tags: chat, smack, asmack

I am developing a chat using quickblox but I am having some problems when I open a new chat. Suddenly I received all the messages that others users sends to me when I was desconnected. The problem is that when I start a chat with user A, I receive the chats from users B, C, D.. in user A chat room.

I have find the way to only show the A users. But the problem is that the server has already sent to me the "disconnected" messages, so when I start a chat to B I do not receive any text because the message that the user B sent to me has been delivered (and ommitted) while I was chating with user A.

How can I do to receive the pending messages (kind of history) or to just retreive the message of the chat I am logged in?

A piece of my code:

```
            // Create Connection.
            Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
            config     = new ConnectionConfiguration(CHAT_SERVER);
            connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                connection.login(chatLogin, password);

                // Create Chat Manager.
                chatManager = connection.getChatManager();



                // Create Chat.
                chat = chatManager.createChat(friendLogin, null);

                //                  // Set listener for outcoming messages.
                //                  chatManager.addChatListener(chatManagerListener);


                // Accept only messages from
                String from_messages = Integer.toString(receiver_chat_id);

                PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class),
                        new FromContainsFilter(from_messages+"-3758@chat.quickblox.com"));

                // Collect these messages
                PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);

                Packet packet = collector.pollResult();

                PacketListener myListener = new PacketListener() {
                    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                        if (packet instanceof Message) {
                            Message msg = (Message) packet;
                            if(msg!=null){
                                // Process message
                                System.out.println("Rebem missatge: " +msg.getBody());

                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                // Register the listener.
                connection.addPacketListener(myListener, filter);


                // Set listener for detect Receiver Status
                if (connection.isConnected()){

                    roster = connection.getRoster();
                    roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
                        public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                        public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
                        public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {}
                        public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {}
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a arraylist and store the receiving offline messages into that array-list. you could add a code in your processPacket(Packet packet) function to add incoming messages to the array-list. or you could use Multimaps(Google Guava) to store all the incoming messages with the key. and when you open the activity that displays the messages from the certain person you could match the name of that person with the key(stored in multimap) and displays the message of that certain person. And the better option is to store all the incomming and outgoing message chat with the certain person so that you could show all the previous chat then you open up the activity.